# c# save resources file as .resx xml file error

Tags: c#, xaml, resources, resx

In my application i have a bunch of string definitions.
I have put them as within the resources of visual studio with the idea so that it would save as an xml .resx file. The reason for this, is that after deployment i would be able to change some string definitions when i need to for some reason.

So, i have set the resources properties build action to be "XamlAppDef" and the Custom tool is automatically set to "PublicResXFileCodeGenerator" by visual studio.
Furthermore i linked system.xaml in my project references.

Although the .resx file is automatically generated, i now get an error during compile:
`The XAML MSBuild task only processes files that contain an '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml}Class' directive. Please refer to documentation for usage of ‘{http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml}Class’`

i tried figuring out how to fix this, but i cant really seem to figure it out. Any thoughts ?

Comment: what does your csproj look like? do you have a the wrong custom tool selected?

Comment: why are you selecting `XamlAppDef`?

Comment: select the `Content` build action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `XamlAppDef` is exactly only for `XAML`, not `RESX` resources. Use the `Content` build action instead.

Comment: Actually.. now that i think of it.. i think i should have generated a `application configuration file` instead of using the resources for strings. the settings file will generate the .config xml

Comment: @Dante1986 bad day huh.